# django model formset factory how to write {{ form.field }}

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

So for forms, if you have quantity = IntegerField() in forms.py, then in the html file you can write {{ form.quantity }} to get the input for the quantity. How can do you the samething for modelformset_factory?

[I've created a formset to ask the user for the item name and quantity. The item name is given by the loop. I need to move the modelformset factory inside the loop for each iteration, but I don't know how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn4nq.png)

```
#views.py
    #for showing items
    if (Items.objects.filter(item_category="Produce").exists()):
        produce = Items.objects.filter(item_category="Produce", show=True, quantity__gte=1)
    if (Items.objects.filter(item_category="Grains").exists()):
        grains = Items.objects.filter(item_category="Grains", show=True, quantity__gte=1)
    if (Items.objects.filter(item_category="Protein/Dairy").exists()):
        protein_dairy = Items.objects.filter(item_category="Protein/Dairy", show=True, quantity__gte=1)
    if (Items.objects.filter(item_category="extras").exists()):
        extras = Items.objects.filter(item_category="extra items", show=True, quantity__gte=1)

    
    #playing with formset
    form_extras = Items.objects.filter(show=True).count()
    formset = modelformset_factory(Cart, form=CustomerOrderForm,extra=form_extras)
    form = formset(queryset=Items.objects.none())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formset(request.POST)
        #work on this
        if form.is_valid():
            print("is valid")
            form = formset(request.POST)
            instances = form.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                #item previously in cart
                if (Cart.objects.filter(username=request.user, item_name=form.cleaned_data.get('item_name')).exists()):
                    cart_instance = Cart.objects.get(username=request.user, item_name=form.cleaned_data.get('item_name'))
                    cart_instance.quantity = cart_instance.quantity + form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
                    cart_instance.save()
                else:
                    #item never in cart, create new instance
                    item_instance = Items.objects.get(item_name=form.cleaned_data.get('item_name'))

                    Cart.objects.create(username=request.user, item_name=form.cleaned_data.get('item_name'), weight=item_instance.weight, quantity=form.cleaned_data.get('quantity'), description=item_instance.description, image=item_instance.image, price=item_instance.price, storage_type=item_instance.storage_type, item_category=item_instance.item_category, limit=item_instance.limit,)
        
            timestamp = datetime.date.today()
            messages.success(request,"Sucessfully added your items to your cart! " + str(timestamp))
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print("form not valid for cart")
            form = formset()

    user_produce_points = request.user.profile.produce_points
    user_grain_points = request.user.profile.grain_points
    user_protein_dairy_points = request.user.profile.protein_dairy_points
    user_extras_points = request.user.profile.extra_items_points
```

Home.html:

```
#home.html
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.management_form }}
        {{form.as_p}} 
        <div class="row">    

          {% for item in produce %}
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

                <img src="/media/{{ item.image }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-center">
                        <b>{% if item.storage_type == "Frozen" %}
                              Frozen 
                            {% endif %}
                        {{ item.item_name }} ({{ item.weight }} oz)</b></h5>

                    <h6 class ="card-title text-center" style="color:green;font-size: 16px;"><b>{{ item.price }} Produce 
                      {% if item.price < 2 %}
                      Point
                      {% else %}
                      Points
                      {% endif %}

                    </b></h6>
                    
                    <p class="card-text">{{ item.description }}</p>
                    <br><br>

                
                      <div class="input-quantity">
                      
                        <input type="hidden" name="form-{{forloop.counter}}-item_name" value="{{ item.item_name }}">
                        {{form.quantity}}
                        {{form.item_name}}
                        {{form.field}}

                        Quantity: <input style="max-width:3em;" type="number" name="form-{{forloop.counter}}-quantity" pattern="[0-9]{3}" min="0" max="{{ item.limit }}">
            
                      </div>

                    
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>

            <button type="submit" style="height:38px;" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp" type="button">Add to Cart</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) always has a nice example, it always helps me.

You sadly didn't post (I'm assuming you didn't) the rest of the view function so I can only guess that `form` in the template refers to the formset created in the view and that is gets passed. And if it does, you would need to first create the for-loop before accessing it in `name="form-{{forloop.counter}}-item_name"`. You could create it like this:

```html
{% for form_line in form %}
    <!--form_line rendering you have-->
    <p>Form #{{ forloop.counter }}</p>
    {{ form_line.quantity }}
    {{ form_line.item_name }}
    {{ form_line.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

In your template you also have the `produce` variable. I am unsure what that refers to, again, maybe because I can't see the whole view function.

Comment: I edited the first post to show the whole views.py. There's also a screenshot that is clickable that was there previously. I wanted to have one submit button for all items that the admin wants to sell. The items are grouped by 4 categories: produce, grain, protein/dairy, and extras. The loop for each category is the same so I didn't post it for every category. The catch is the loop comes from the "Items" model (basically the inventory that is used by admins) while the user only can insert stuff into the "Cart" model. So unfortunately, I'm not able to use the loop you've shown.

Comment: the "name="form-{{forloop.counter}}-item_name"" part is because when i inspected the of default django {{ formset }}, I noticed that it says "form-0-item_name" where item_name is my variable, the next iteration is just "form-1-item_name" so I wanted to try and see if it would work... It didn't. If there is a way to declare the whole "block" of form using a simple tag like {{ form.fields }} or {{ form.item_name }} and {{ form.quantity }} then that would be a life saver. I have to really think about how I can fit in the for loop for form. I don't think it would be easy...